# Is it possible to update a struct from a thread?

Tags: rust

In Rust is it possible to update a struct from a thread started in one of the structs member functions?

I have an example below and the error I am getting is that you can't use self as a variable name.

```
use std::time::Duration;
use glib::{clone, Continue, MainContext, PRIORITY_DEFAULT};
use adw::{Application, ApplicationWindow};
use adw::prelude::*;
use std::thread;

const APP_ID: &str = "org.struct_threads";

fn main() {
    let app = Application::builder().application_id(APP_ID).build();
    app.connect_activate(build_ui);
    app.run();
}

pub fn build_ui(app: &Application) {    
   let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .build(); 

    let window_clone = window.clone();
    let astruct = aStruct { aString : String::new(), aBool : false };
    astruct.update_string();
    while true {
        println!("aString = {}", astruct.aString);
    };
}

struct aStruct {
    aString : String,
    aBool   : bool
}

impl aStruct {
    pub fn update_string(&mut self) {
        let (sender, receiver) = MainContext::channel(PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    
        thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                //let thisString = "";
                if self.aString == "Value two" {
                    sender.send("Value one").expect("Could not send through channel");
                    //thisString = "Value two";
                }
                else {
                    sender.send("Value two").expect("Could not send through channel");
                    //thisString = "Value one";
                }
                //self.aStinrg = thisString.to_string();
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
            };
        });
    
        receiver.attach(
            None,
            clone!(@weak self => @default-return Continue(false),
                move |reciever_string| {
                    self.aString = reciever_string;
                    Continue(true)
                }
           ),
        );
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error: proc macro panicked
   --> src/main.rs:99:13
    |
99  | /             clone!(@weak self => @default-return Continue(false),
100 | |                 move |reciever_string| {
101 | |                     self.aString = reciever_string;
102 | |                     Continue(true)
103 | |                 }
104 | |            ),
    | |____________^
    |
    = help: message: Can't use `self` as variable name. Try storing it in a temporary variable or rename it using `as`.
```

If I clone self and pass a normal variable name into the receiver I get an error stating that the struct does not implement `Downgrade` which doesn't seem to be implementable for booleans.

I get the same `Downgrade` error if I try and move this block into a non member function of the struct and call it separately.

Downgrade error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `aStruct: Downgrade` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:99:13
    |
99  | /             clone!(@weak self_clone => @default-return Continue(false),
100 | |                 move |reciever_string| {
101 | |                     self.aString = reciever_string.to_string();
102 | |                     Continue(true)
103 | |                 }
104 | |            ),
    | |____________^ the trait `Downgrade` is not implemented for `aStruct`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `Downgrade`:
              &T
              ATContext
              AboutDialog
              AboutWindow
              Accessible
              Action
              ActionBar
              ActionGroup
            and 493 others
    = note: required for `&aStruct` to implement `Downgrade`
    = note: this error originates in the macro `clone` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Finally if I just try and update the struct from within the thread using either self or a copy I get an error stating that the value does not live long enough. Is there way to update a struct from a thread?

Comment: Using `clone!` here is probably unwarranted.

Comment: What should I use instead? I just tried `_` and that threw an error.

Comment: I think this entire approach is invalid, but that's just a thought. The way I'd approach this is by sending messages, but as you're calling a block with `move` that severely complicates things, the thread ends up *owning* `self`. If you need shared access, you need `Arc`.

Comment: The first question I have is why does this thing spawn a thread, rather than something else spawns a thread that happens to include this struct?

Comment: Do you know where I can find an example of someone using the method you are suggesting?

Comment: Ignoring this code, what are you trying to achieve? What problem do you need to solve?

Comment: For this method the results are the same whether you call the thread from within the struct or from a separate method and pass the struct to that method.

Comment: I want to update a struct with data from a web request I will run every minute or so.

Comment: Consider interior mutability by making the mutable properties wrapped in `Arc`. That way your function does not need a `&mut` ref, it just takes a regular one.

Comment: If you have not already, read [this chapter of the rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-00-concurrency.html).